# Exception MongoCursorException: couldn't send query: ët§ôï9·H'ï¯¤7·ø?u§Ht§ ö·Ì­u§®u§Ì½u§4e

Tags: php, php-mongodb

I am trying to talk to a remote MongoDB server from my system. The code i use is like this

```
$con_string='mongodb://server_ip:27017';
$m = new Mongo($con_string);
$temp=$m->selectDB("DBName");
try {
    $mc=$temp->collection_name->find()->limit(5);
    var_dump($mc->info());
    var_dump(iterator_to_array($mc));
}
catch (MongoCursorException $e) {
    echo "error message: ".$e->getMessage()."</br>";
echo "error code: ".$e->getCode();
}
```

Now i get the following message from Xdebug

```
MongoCursorException: couldn't send query: ët§ôï9·H'ï¯¤7·ø?u§Ht§ ö·Ì­u§®u§Ì½u§4e
```

Why is this exception raised and why is there junk at the end of exception. I dont get this exception every time but 5 out of 6 times.
Also the message i got from catch block is

```
error message: couldn't send query:  QY¥ôï9·H§ï³¤7·DCY¥h §
error code: 14
```

`The error code 14 means "C socket error on send."` says the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongocursorexception.php).
What does this error mean?

A guy in chat suggested that the junk is indicator that the data might not be utf8_encoded but i am doing a simple `find()` with no criteria so what do i need to encode?

**EDIT:**

To get around this scenario i wrote this

```
function getCursor($conn,$db_name,$coll_name,$query_options=array(),$fields=array(),$cursor_options=array(),$max_tries=0) {
    $counter=0;
    while(1) {
        try {
            $cursor=new MongoCursor($conn,$db_name.'.'.$coll_name,$query_options,$fields);

            if (array_key_exists('count',$cursor_options))
                return $cursor->count();
            if (array_key_exists('limit',$cursor_options))
                $cursor=$cursor->limit($cursor_options['limit']);
            if (array_key_exists('skip',$cursor_options))
                $cursor=$cursor->skip($cursor_options['skip']);
            if (array_key_exists('sort',$cursor_options))
                $cursor=$cursor->sort($cursor_options['sort']);

            return $cursor;
        }
        catch (MongoCursorException $e) {
            $counter+=1;
            if ($max_tries>0) {
                if ($counter>$max_tries)
                    echo "error message: ".$e->getMessage()."\n";
                    echo "error code: ".$e->getCode()."\n";
                    return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The functions takes the query parameters and then send the query to the server and if the `MongoCursorException` is raised it sends the query again. It does this `$max_tries` times. If `$max_tries` is set to 0 it will keep on sending this query to the server until the query succeeds. Maybe this is stupid, i should have set this to some fixed value like 50. On success the function returns the cursor except when your looking for the `count` and in that case it returns the `count`

Comment: Yes it looks like some encoding problem but that must not mean it is one. Does some other query work?

Comment: @hakre This query doesnt show this exception always. Its like 5 out of 6 times and that is the case with other queries too

Comment: Disable APC if you have enabled it. Disasble xdebug if you have enabled it. Does the exception still occur 5 out of 6 times? Which PHP  version are you using?

Comment: @hakre i dont have apc enabled but i have xdebug and my PHP version is 5.3.10 and and mongodb's php extension version is 1.2.10 and the MongoDB server i am connecting to is 2.0.6

Comment: Try without xdebug, just in case it bites and you want to ensure that it's the mongodb extension and not some other extension.

Comment: @hakre Wow i disabled xdebug and i havent seen the exception even once in 10 times. How did xdebug affect it

Comment: @hakre is there any xdebug's configuration option i can set so that queries dont generate that exception and i can keep xdebug enabled. Life without xdebug is difficult

Comment: Uhm, which version of xdebug extension do you use? This might be fixed already. And which OS is the server (unix/linux/osx/win; 32/64bit)? If this is a bug - either in xdebug or mongodb - I'd say you're lucky because the author of xdebug is also involved with mongodb.

Comment: @hakre i am using xdebug 2.2.0 and the server is centos 6.2 64-bit

Comment: Please upgrade to Xdebug 2.2.1, this *might* already solve your issue.

Comment: @hakre upgrading to xdebug 2.2.1 solves the problem. I still see that thing sometimes but that sometimes is like 1 out of 100 and that 1 out of 100 occurs even if i have disabled xdebug. Anyway, answer this question so i can mark it as accepted

Comment: If you still have the problem this is not the solution yet. Can you run tests to check if it goes completely away if you fully disable xdebug? Sure I can add the suggestion to updated to the latest and greatest as an answer below.

Comment: @Hakre all right i'll work for some time disabling xdebug completely

Comment: @hakre I disabled xdebug completely and and worked for some time but still i can see the exception with the junk characters once in a while. To get around that i wrote a function that tries the code in a block a certain number of times. See my edit in the question

Comment: @hakre i used RockMongo to inspect my remote mongoDB server and now again i am facing these problems. I have disabled xdebug. Do you see what is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your string looks like that if:

- You have a charset encoding issue
- Memory is broken

As in your code not much strings are involved, the chances that this is an encoding issue are not very high.

But as Xdebug is a PHP extension that deals a lot with internals, breaking memory can be one thing.

An easy way to find out is to disable the extension you suspect that is causing the issue, e.g. xdebug.

It is also useful for documentation purposes tp write down which PHP and extension versions you are using as well as on which operating system. I asked for that in comments, it's a list like:

```
PHP 5.3.10
Mongodb Extension 1.2.10
Mongodb Server 2.0.6
Xdebug 2.2.0    
Centos 6.2 64-bit
```

Checking [the website for xdebug](http://xdebug.org) shows that there is a new version available. As you have found out earlier by disabling xdebug that it influences the result, try with updating the xdebug extension and see if it helps.

Even if it does, keep your version list for further reference (as well with a short description of the problem), because in case the problem is not fully solved with the upgrade, this information can be very useful at a later time to do a useful bug-report. Those internal problems in the software are sometimes hard to spot, so the information can help to reproduce easier then or to identify the areas involved.

Comment: How did you realize that xdebug was the culprit?

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed in Mongo driver v1.3+

ref: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/mongodb-user/IJ1n_Xt_al8

Downloads: http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/